# Android : can we show many locations coordinates(lat n long) in a single google map?

Tags: android, google-maps, location, coordinates

heloo, :) 
i have coordinates (lat n long) of ten locations in database, is it posible to show them in one map on android? i am newbie to android so you guys can help me.Thak you so much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it's called a marker.

It's pretty simple

```
GoogleMap map = ... // get a map.
// Add a marker at San Francisco.
Marker marker = map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
 .position(new LatLng(37.7750, 122.4183))
 .title("San Francisco")
 .snippet("Population: 776733"));
```

Java doc here http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html

If you haven't got as far as adding a map. You should follow this guide https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/map